# Error:Error: try is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)

Tags: android

I want to display a pdf file in my app . Where i was stored pdf file in raw folder . Where pdf name is "try.pdf" my code is this :

```
File file = new File(R.raw.try);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path , "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try {
    startActivity(pdfIntent ); 
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"No Application available to viewPDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But this code shows an error `Error:Error: try is not a valid resource name 
     (reserved Java keyword)`
Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the error

```
File file = new File(R.raw.try);
```

Rename your file `try.pdf` to anything else (except whats mentioned here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). You can't use a Java-reserved keyword, which `try` is.

Comment: @MichaelDodd: Exactly :)

Comment: The problem goes far beyond this, though. You cannot do `new File(R.raw.anything)`, for any value of `anything`. Raw resources are not files.

Comment: So how i can call `R.row.anything`

Answer (score 0):

Important point: You **can not** use a **reserved** keywords.