# Error while generate signed APK

Tags: android, apk, signed, generate

After generate signed APK i find this error message.

```
G:\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: 
  Error: switch is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you arrived at this error?

Comment: just after i do generate signed my apk it dont finished and give me that message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Error: try is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644785/errorerror-try-is-not-a-valid-resource-name-reserved-java-keyword)

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a resource in that file with the name "switch", which is not allowed. Rename it to something else and that should work fine.

Comment: Not sure why I'm being downvoted, this is the correct answer. "Switch" cannot be used as a resource name because the resource names are used as Java variables in the R.java and "switch" is a reserves keyword in java...